# Compiled Proxy Class (in bin) vs. Web Reference

Tags: asp.net, proxy-classes, web-reference

I have a handful of ASP.NET websites which communicate with different instances of SQL Server 2005 via a web reference to the report server's web service. However, today I toyed with the notion of using the WSDL tool to create a proxy class from one of the SQL Server instances and, in turn, using the proxy to create a dll (before doing so, I modified the proxy's constructor to accept a URL - so that I could point the proxy to any of the web service instances).

I'm pretty sure that the web service should be pretty, if not completely, static, in terms of updates. So, my question is: are there any drawbacks for using the compiled proxy class (in the bin directory), as opposed to using the proxy class (auto-generated), itself? If not, what are some motivations for going one way or the other?

Answer (score 2):

As to my knowledge, there is absolutely no difference between both of them. The Service Reference does exactly what the svcutil also does, but allows the user to do it in an easier way. Service Reference is just a warpper around the svcutil.exe and it does nothing more than what the basic svcutil.exe does.

Thanks